# C# how to know which properties have been set to validate & flag EFCore modified flag

Tags: c#, validation, object, entity-framework-core

Essentially, I want to know if there is a way to know which properties on an object have been set, so that I know which properties to flag as modified for EFCore, and my validator.

Let's say for example I have these two classes:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Bar TheBar { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

I also have to assume that a null value or a default value could be a valid value for any property. Meaning I can't do a check like `if (prop.equals(default(PropType)))` to check if a property has been set.

What I have at the moment is a generic update method that looks like this:

```cs
public ExecutionResult<TModel> ExecuteUpdate<TModel>(TModel model, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] updatedProperties)
{
    // Validation and EFCore calls
}
```

Using that method I can do something like this, which allows me manually set which properties will be updated based on the Http endpoint. ie. an update password endpoint would only change the password property on a model, not every property on the model:

```cs
var myFooOne = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "New Name",
    Content = "Some new content"
}
// This allows me validate only the updated properties, and allow me to attatch the model to EFCore and only set the modified flag on the modified properties to create an optimal query
endPoint.ExecuteUpdate(myFooOne, foo => foo.Name, foo.Content);
```

The problem with my current solution is when I need to validate/update any non-primitive property. Using my current solution, I would have to do something like this:

```cs
// Only the Name property of the TheBar property was updated
var myFooTwo = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    TheBar = new Bar
    {
        // Id of a specific Bar already in the database
        Id = 5,
        Name = "New Name"
    }
}
endPoint.ExecuteUpdate(myFooTwo, foo => foo.TheBar.Name);
```

There are two issues with this, using the selector I can only get as specific as the direct object itself, I can't tell EFCore this way which specific properties on the `TheBar` property are dirty, I can only flag the entire property object as dirty (which is inefficient). And two, Expression selectors like this won't even work with anything more complicated than selecting an immediate property, ie. `foo.TheBar` is fine, but `foo.TheBar.Name` throws an ArgumentException. This gets more complicated with collections, and even further nested objects.

An idea I have is to wrap all my types in a wrapper like so:

```cs
enum WrapperStatus
{
    Unknown,
    NotSet,
    Set
}

class Wrapper<T>
{
    T Value { get; }

    WrapperStatus Status { get; }
}

class FooEntity
{
    Wrapper<int> Id { get; set; }

    Wrapper<Bar> TheBar { get; set; }

    // Same for rest of properties and all models
}
```

Then when validating and updating, I can do something like this:

```cs
var foo = new FooEntity
{
    Id = new Wrapper<int>
        {
            Value = 1,
            Status = WrapperStatus.Set
        },
    Name = new Wrapper<string>
        {
            Value = "New Name",
            WrapperStatus.Set
        }
}
```

Basically my idea was to create a wrapper around each model, and each property of each model to flag with the `WrapperStatus` flag, and I could add as many different flags as needed: `Updated, Null, UnChanged` etc.
Once I validated the model, which would be easy to do because I know which properties need to be checked based off of the flags, I can use an adapter to convert the WrapperModel to the actual model, and pass it to EFCore while also being able to easily set the modfied flag on the required properties. The only reason I haven't done this yet is because it would essentially require making the model twice, one for the EFCore model, and again for the wrapper model. Now I can make the wrapper easier to initialize using `operator` keyword and some static initializers, but I wanted to see if there was an easier way first.

I know this is a lot of info, but I can clarify anything that is needed.

Comment: EF Core already tracking changes on the entity, you don't need to replicate it

Comment: It's also for my validator, let's say I want a name field to not be null or empty. This check should only happen when they name field is updated. However, not all Http endpoints update the name field, so if an endpoint only updates the content field, then the validator will fail because it does not know that it shouldn't check the name field, it should only check the content field. Basically the validator needs to know which properties should be validated, and then pass that information to EFCore.

Comment: If you are going to save entity, you better validate whole entity, so valid entity is saved. Validation is cheap enough to validate whole entity instead of building complicated tracking system

Comment: But then I have to retrieve the entire entity every time I want to validate something of it. Or retrieve entire collections of entities, and potentially any nested entities. If a property depends on the value of another property to validate, then I can retrieve the dependent property, but many properties can be validated without the need of other properties.

Comment: You already have an instance of entity which you are validating. Can you show code where you validating an entity.

Comment: So say for example you are updating the password of a user, the frontend can post to the server with the user ID, and the new password, then you can make a new user object, with the user ID, and password, and attach that to EFCore to update the user. I shouldn't need to get the entire entity from the database just to validate a password.

Comment: Ok, then you don't need whole entity, validate password, create entity instance with new password, attach it tot he DbContext and mark Password property as modified `db.Entry(userInstance).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = true`.

Comment: But that doesn't validate it

Comment: Sorry, I misread, but this would mean having possibly many duplicate validations of the same properties. If one method only updated the name, and another endpoint updated the name, address, etc (hypothetically), then you are validating the same properties in many places which sounds horrible to maintain.

Comment: Yes you will validate properties many times, but you can use only one validation method for every property and reuse it everywhere you need.